# jquery.filer remove already uploaded files

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, upload

I have problem with jquery.filer!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#filer_input').filer({
          showThumbs: true,
          templates: {
            box: '<ul class="jFiler-items-list jFiler-items-grid"></ul>',
            item: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                        <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo: 25}}</b></span>\
                                        <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-size2}}</span>\
                                    </div>\
                                    {{fi-image}}\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-left"></ul>\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                        <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </li>',
            itemAppend: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                        <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                        <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                            <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo: 25}}</b></span>\
                                            <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-size2}}</span>\
                                        </div>\
                                        {{fi-image}}\
                                    </div>\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                        <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                            <li><span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-icon}}</span><span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-size2}}</span></li>\
                                        </ul>\
                                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                            <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                        </ul>\
                                    </div>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </li>',
            itemAppendToEnd: false,
            removeConfirmation: true,
            _selectors: {
            list: '.jFiler-items-list',
            item: '.jFiler-item',
            remove: '.jFiler-item-trash-action'
            }
            },
         addMore: true,
         limit:8,
         maxSize:2,
         extensions: ['jpg','gif','png'],
         files: [
        <?php 
        $path=SITEBASE.'uploads/';

        $i = 1;

        foreach (unserialize($input['gallery']) as $key => $photo) : ?>
            {
            name: "photo<?=$i?>.jpg",
            size: <?=filesize(UPLOAD.$photo)?>,
            type: "image/jpg",
            file: "<?=$path.$photo?>"
            },

        <?php 
        $i++;

        endforeach; ?>    
        ]

          });       
        });
```

that's my "configuration" of filer.

```
<form name="photoform" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="filer_input" multiple="multiple">
<input type="submit" name="photoformuploadphoto" value="SEND" />
</form>
```

Now, in results, everything displays perfectly.
All pictures already uploaded display on website.

I try to upload new files and add to database.

```
$uploader = new Uploader();
    $data = $uploader->upload($_FILES['files'], array(
        'limit' => 8, //Maximum Limit of files. {null, Number}
        'maxSize' => 2, //Maximum Size of files {null, Number(in MB's)}
        'extensions' => array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'), //Whitelist for file extension. {null, Array(ex: array('jpg', 'png'))}
        'required' => false, //Minimum one file is required for upload {Boolean}
        'uploadDir' => UPLOAD, //Upload directory {String}
        'title' => array('auto', 30), //New file name {null, String, Array} *please read documentation in README.md
        'removeFiles' => true, //Enable file exclusion {Boolean(extra for jQuery.filer), String($_POST field name containing json data with file names)}
        'onRemove' => 'onFilesRemoveCallback' //A callback function name to be called by removing files (must return an array) | ($removed_files) | Callback
    ));

    if($data['isComplete']){
        $files = $data['data'];

        foreach($files["metas"] as $value){  

        $gallery[]=$value["name"];

        imageResize($value["file"], UPLOAD.'thumb/'.$value["name"], '190', '114', 0);

    }

    $sql_update="UPDATE `".PREFIX."users` SET `gallery`='".serialize($gallery)."' WHERE `id`=".$_POST["id"];
    query($sql_update);

       // echo '<pre>';print_r($files);echo '</pre>';
    }

    if($data['hasErrors']){
        $errors = $data['errors'];
        //print_r($errors);
    }

    function onFilesRemoveCallback($removed_files){
        foreach($removed_files as $key=>$value){
            $file = UPLOAD . $value;
            $thumb = UPLOAD.'thumb/' . $value;

            if(file_exists($file)){
                unlink($file);
            }
            if(file_exists($thumb)){
                unlink($thumb);
            }
        }

        return $removed_files;
    }
```

Unfortunately, **$files = $data['data']** return only new uploaded files. 
That's mean my already uploaded files are removed.

Do you have idea how sort it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:
1. get the old files from mysql in array
2. add the uploaded files to the old files

```
$db_images = $db_row['images']; //only example

if($data['isComplete']){
    $files = $data['data'];

    foreach($files["files"] as $value){
        $db_images[] = $value;
    }
}

// now $db_images is ready
// write your query to update
```